# Custom Markers in Google Maps app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using a google maps javascript application and I want to use a custom image for one of the markers.

here is an example of the code I think I'm using to get the marker.

```
 var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
 GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = GXml.parse(data);
   markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

   var sidebar2 = document.getElementById('sidebar2');
   sidebar2.innerHTML = '';
   if (markers.length == 0) {
     document.getElementById('alert_div').innerHTML = "<a>No Results found</a>";
     document.getElementById('alert_div').style.display = 'block';

     map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.178873,2.8125), 2);
     return;
   }
   showSidebar();   
   var limitsearch = document.getElementById('limitsearch').value;
   var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
   if (limitsearch <= markers.length){
   for (var i = 0; i < limitsearch; i++) {
     var name = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
     var phone = markers[i].getAttribute('phone');
     if (phone == 0){phone = '';}
     var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
     var distance = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('distance'));
     var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lat')),
                             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lng')));

     var marker = createMarker(point, name, address);
     map.addOverlay(marker);
     var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, phone, name, address, distance);
     sidebar2.appendChild(sidebarEntry);
     bounds.extend(point);
   }}
   else{
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var name = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
     var phone = markers[i].getAttribute('phone');
     if (phone == 0){phone = '';}
     var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
     var distance = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('distance'));
     var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lat')),
                             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lng')));

     var marker = createMarker(point, name, address);
     map.addOverlay(marker);
     var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, phone, name, address, distance);
     sidebar2.appendChild(sidebarEntry);
     bounds.extend(point); 
   }

   }




   map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
  showSidebar();
  getAlert();
 });
```

}

Comment: What is in `data`? Can you provide more of the code you're using?

Comment: sure. I am using the Google Maps Store Locator. I have editi my post

Comment: You should also look into the v3 api for google maps. I can update my answer with v3 code if you find it useful.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Comment: can you post the `createMarker` method?

Comment: function createMarker(point, name, address) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }

Comment: Ok, you can either set the marker in the createMarker method or change it using the returned object. @bryan's answer below shows examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a replacement for `createMarker` to support an icon

```
function createMarker(point, name, address, markerIcon) {
  var markerOptions = {}
  if (markerIcon !== undefined) {
    markerOptions = { icon: markerIcon };
  }
  marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
  var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address;
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); 
  });
  return marker; 
}
```

You then can pass in a GIcon object as the last option if you want. You'll need to initialize it like so:

```
var myIcon = new GIcon();
myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(16, 16);
myIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(4, 7);
myIcon.image = "http://www.url.com/somepic.png";
var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, myIcon);
```

You'll need to decide on the size and anchor locations

Also see these resources from the google docs:

- [Icons Overview](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Icons_overview)
- [Simple Icon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/icon-simple.html)
- [Complex/Custom Icon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/icon-custom.html)

Comment: is this for a favicon only? I just want to replace the default marker with my own image

Comment: Nope, any image will work. I'm just using my site's favicon for this particular marker.

Comment: Sure, provide the createMarker() function please.

Comment: function createMarker(point, name, address) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work. I'm still having trouble making it work with my code :(